# Making a responsive navigation bar with a search button

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a responsive navigation bar using bootstrap. I want to build like http://wordpress.org/support/topic/want-to-move-search-option-from-header-to-navigation-bar .
.

But the search button don't go to the right and when collapsed the tabs split and move to the line below. At the place of Download Wordpress button I want LogIn and SignUp buttons. On collapsing the brand name, search button and the bars for opening the menu should be shown in same line.

Can somebody please tell how to do it? [See my code](http://jsfiddle.net/8hrnkbaL/)

```
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" style="float: right;" role="search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test Yourself</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Interesting Questions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ask Queries</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">SignUp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LogIn</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

.navbar {
    min-height: 120px;
}

.navbar .container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "jokerman";
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px)   {
    .navbar-nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:  none;
    }
}
```

Comment: is somebody in the process of answering ?

Comment: can you show how it looks in full view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't really understand if your `search-input` should be visible in xs view but here is something working :*

**Js Fidlle** : http://jsfiddle.net/8hrnkbaL/1/

*The first problem in your fiddle was that bootstrap was loaded before jQuery, but **jQuery must be load in first**...*

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div style="clear:both"></div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test Yourself</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Interesting Questions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ask Queries</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">SignUp</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LogIn</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                          <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: really great sir but I was looking something like this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-build-a-three-line-drop-down-menu-for-a-responsive-website-in-jquery

Comment: the search button should be at the top and not at the bottom

Comment: SOrry I was sleeping (Europa) something like http://jsfiddle.net/8hrnkbaL/2/ , just move the form tag in first position...

Comment: 90% as I want but when full width I want search button to be shown in the same line as Brand name floated to right. And on collapsing it should show a search icon clicking on which only search bar should be shown. Please see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-build-a-three-line-drop-down-menu-for-a-responsive-website-in-jquery in different sizes. Can you make it similar?

Comment: Bernard, I love your menu system. I am going to be using it on our new site. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I drew up this example for you, this is what I meant by keeping it simple, Feel free to use it and edit for mobile using css3 media queries.
p.s you can also use:

```
position:absolue;right:7px;
```

for the menu toggle button on the right for mobile
and you can also use:

```
position:absolue;left:7px;
```

for the ul on the left, Good luck - Millzie :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My menu V.1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.menu-right').click(function(){
   var animationTime = 800;
   if($('.menu').css('height') == '60px'){
    $('.menu').animate({'height':'80px'}, animationTime, 'linear');
   }else if($('.menu').css('height') == '80px'){
    $('.menu').animate({'height':'60px'}, animationTime, 'linear');
   }
  });
 });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;border-radius:0;font-family:sans;}
 div.menu{width:100%;height:60px;background-color:#660033;overflow:hidden;}
 ul.menu-ul{float:left;padding-left:7px;}
 li.menu-li{display:inline;list-style:none;font-size:15px;line-height:60px;margin-right:7px;}
 li.menu-li:hover{border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF;color:#FFFFFF;}
 div.menu-right{float:right;line-height:60px;font-size:15px;margin-right:7px;}
 div.menu-right:hover{color:#FFFFFF;}
 /*search form*/
 input.search{width:900px;height:20px;margin-top:-3px;margin-left:7px;background-color:#FFFFFF;}
 input.search-button{width:70px;height:20px;margin-top:-3px;margin-left:4px;background-color:#FFFFFF;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-ul">
   <li class="menu-li">Menu item one</li>
   <li class="menu-li">Menu item two</li>
   <li class="menu-li">Menu item three</li>
   <li class="menu-li">Menu item four</li>
   <li class="menu-li">Menu item five</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="menu-right">Search</div>
  <form>
   <input type="text" class="search" value="search for something" />
   <input type="submit" class="search-button" value="search" />
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```